# Выбор способа реализации программы

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Привет всем.

Вопрос, конечно, туповат, но я совсем новичок в программировании, хоть и создаю небольшие проекты. Ну, впрочем не важен уровень моих знаний. Вопрос заключается в том, что я хочу написать проект - большая программа с множеством окон. Писать, разумеется, на c# в visual studio.

У меня такой вопрос. В моей программе будет много окон. Что лучше делать - добавлять множество form или лучше иметь одну форму и подключать классы? Как удобней писать и как это влияет на производительность программы?

Comment: >иметь одну форму и подключать классы

это как? 

> как это влияет на производительность программы

не стоит раньше времени задумываться о производительности. Тем более, что если ваша софтина будет использовать какие-либо "тяжелые" операции (будь то работа с БД, веб-запросы или длительные вычисления), то думать о производительности форм вам надо будет в самую последнюю очередь. 

Тем более, это надо очень сильно постараться, чтобы одни лишь формы посадили производительность

Comment: Я имел ввиду что в программе будет всего одно о окно .а весь контент реализовать с помощью классов, а потом уже делать ну например кнопку где пользователь нажимает например на кнопку регистрации.. Есть два варианта реализовать это . Первый это сделать еще одну form и в функции кнопки написать ссылку на эту форму . Второй вариант форма одна и таже только в кнопку прописать функцию с ссылкой на класс . Тогда форма остается а весь контент регистрации выводиться из класса ..

Comment: Попробуйте использовать Model-View-Presenter. Модель (Model), которая содержит всю бизнес-логику экрана; Вид/Представление (View), который знает, как отобразить те или иные данные; Представитель (Presenter), который является связующий звеном — реагирует на действия пользователя во View, изменяя Model, и наоборот.

http://habrahabr.ru/post/211899/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как удобнее писать — зависит от архитектуры вашей программы, и только от неё.

Например, если ваш UI закодирован в коде окна, то наверное выгоднее иметь отдельные классы. Если у вас одно и то же окно, подключающее различный контент в зависимости от `DataContext`'а, то наверное проще иметь один оконный класс.

О производительности в этой точке думать вовсе не стоит: возможная разница в производительности составляет величину порядка меньше миллисекунды, что исчезающе мало по сравнению со, скажем, скоростью появления самого окна на экране.